# Missing global conv object in pandas plotting.py code?

Tags: python, plot, pandas

I am trying to work through some example using pandas.  I load a DataFrame from Yahoo, export it out to a file, read it into a DataFrame, and create Series I would like to plot.  When I use the plot code it throws an error.  The error is NameError: global name 'conv' is not defined.  The code and the full error are below.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('figure', figsize=(8, 7))


aapl = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', 
                                 start=datetime.datetime(2006, 10, 1), 
                                 end=datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 10))

aapl.to_csv('data/aapl_ohlc.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('data/aapl_ohlc.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

close_px = df['Adj Close']
mavg = pd.rolling_mean(close_px, 40)

close_px.plot(label='AAPL')
mavg.plot(label='mavg')
plt.legend()
```

It throws the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-34eecf8ee548> in <module>()
      1 from pylab import *
----> 2 close_px.plot(label='AAPL')
      3 mavg.plot(label='mavg')
      4 plt.legend()

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py in plot_series(series, label, kind, use_index, rot, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, ax, style, grid, legend, logx, logy, secondary_y, **kwds)
   1827                      secondary_y=secondary_y, **kwds)
   1828 
-> 1829     plot_obj.generate()
   1830     plot_obj.draw()
   1831 

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py in generate(self)
    903         self._compute_plot_data()
    904         self._setup_subplots()
--> 905         self._make_plot()
    906         self._post_plot_logic()
    907         self._adorn_subplots()

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py in _make_plot(self)
   1354 
   1355                 if self._is_datetype():
-> 1356                     left, right = _get_xlim(lines)
   1357                     ax.set_xlim(left, right)
   1358 

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py in _get_xlim(lines)
   2507     for l in lines:
   2508         x = l.get_xdata()
-> 2509         left = min(_maybe_convert_date(x[0]), left)
   2510         right = max(_maybe_convert_date(x[-1]), right)
   2511     return left, right

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py in _maybe_convert_date(x)
   2514 def _maybe_convert_date(x):
   2515     if not com.is_integer(x):
-> 2516         conv_func = conv._dt_to_float_ordinal
   2517         if isinstance(x, datetime.time):
   2518             conv_func = conv._to_ordinalf

NameError: global name 'conv' is not defined
```

**update per comment**

code

```
import pandas.tseries.converter
print(dir(pandas.tseries.converter))
```

output

```
['AutoLocator', 'DatetimeConverter', 'Formatter', 'FreqGroup', 'HOURS_PER_DAY', 'Index', 'Locator', 'MINUTES_PER_DAY', 'MUSECONDS_PER_DAY', 'MilliSecondLocator', 'PandasAutoDateFormatter', 'PandasAutoDateLocator', 'Period', 'PeriodConverter', 'PeriodIndex', 'SECONDS_PER_DAY', 'TimeConverter', 'TimeFormatter', 'TimeSeries_DateFormatter', 'TimeSeries_DateLocator', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__initializing__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '_annual_finder', '_daily_finder', '_dt_to_float_ordinal', '_from_ordinal', '_get_default_annual_spacing', '_monthly_finder', '_quarterly_finder', '_to_ordinalf', 'com', 'compat', 'date_range', 'dates', 'datetime', 'frequencies', 'get_datevalue', 'get_finder', 'has_level_label', 'lib', 'lrange', 'nonsingular', 'np', 'period_break', 'pydt', 'register', 'relativedelta', 'time2num', 'timedelta', 'tools', 'units']
```

Comment: If you look at the code in `plotting.py`, you see that `conv` is the name given to `pandas.tseries.converter` after it's imported.  What happens when you type `import pandas.tseries.converter`?

Comment: I will look I am very new to python.

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: No, I mean what happens if at the console, you type `import pandas.tseries.converter`, and then `print(dir(pandas.tseries.converter))`?  Set your code aside for the moment.

Comment: added to bottom of question since output was too long for comment.

Comment: Who down voted it without leaving a comment!? Looks good to me. It is strange that I clearly see `'_dt_to_float_ordinal'` in `print(dir(pandas.tseries.converter))`. Which version are you using?

Comment: I downloaded from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyparsing

Comment: pandas‑0.13.1.win32‑py3.3.exe

Comment: @CTZhu: the only thing I can think of is that something's going wrong with the import and so `conv` isn't being set.  I was expecting to hear that the import produced an `ImportError`.

Comment: Could this be relevant?  I have two plotting.py files one located in C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tools and another in C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries?

Comment: No, we all have two `plot.py`. BTW, can't reproduce the symptom using `pandas-0.13.1` on both `python 2.7` and `python-3.3` on `OSX-64bit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a new IPython Notebook session cleared it up.  I am not really sure what I managed to do to myself but lesson learned.

One thing of note I did have to add

```
from imp import reload
```

to the file lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py